# How to set project ID in google cloud storage builder?

Tags: java, json, firebase, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to upload an Image to `Google Cloud storage` but while creating `StorageOptions` I am getting `project must be specified.` exception.

I followed the official documentation and choose to use `Json` credentials after performing following steps:

1. Create a new `Service Account Key`
2. In `Role` I have selected `Owner` (change it later)
3. Download the `Json` key and using following sample to connect with it

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
   Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder()
           .setCredentials(ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream("/Users/test/sample/app/project-936c0c6ef960.json")))
           .build()
           .getService();

   String bucketName = "Sample";
   Bucket bucket = storage.create(BucketInfo.of(bucketName));
   System.out.printf("Bucket %s created.%n", bucket.getName());
   }
   ```

   What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Hrm, looks like you're right. There doesn't seem to be a way to set a project when creating a bucket with the Java client. I filed a bug: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/issues/2643

You can probably get around this by specifying the project when setting up the StorageOptions:

```
StorageOptions.newBuilder().setProjectId("my-project-id")
    //continue as normal
```